# jQuery mobile and function calling?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have weird problem that I cant figure it out. I've made mobile app with jQuery and Phonegap. In my app I am calling some web-services to get data and when I do that it takes a few seconds so I want to show to user a loading bar. I have written my own loading presentation with .gif picture which I add to screen with javascript before service request. My problem is that this .gif is not added to screen until web service function is almost half or completely through. Like I would call it asynchronously, but as far as know It is all on one thread. So how could I achieve this?

(pseudo code)

```
showLoading();
callWebService();
stopLoading();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues similar to this, which have been resolved by adding the later actions into a setTimeout with interval 0:

```
showLoading();
setTimeout(function(){
    callWebService();
    stopLoading();
}, 0);
```

More detail about this technique can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-does-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-help), but basically the timeout allows the browser to complete any UI updates (such as rendering your loading image) before continuing to execute the JavaScript code.

Comment: that almost did the trick... :D I mean it rendered the picture so you gave me right answer, but another silly thing. I want to render loading gif and gif doesnt show animation. It just render first gif picture. Is there any way to fix that? (dont think so)

Comment: hmm - not sure about that - maybe you should start another question?